# How convert 2 separate arrays for each of the object in JSON data?

Tags: arrays, json

Manage to generate a proper JSON data from a url. But how to create 2 separate arrays using the JSON data to have the following output?

```
PrefectureCode = ["1", "2", ....]
PrefectureName = ["A", "B", ....]
```

*** Resulting JSON ****

```
{
  "message" : null,
  "result" : [
    {
      "prefCode" : 1,
      "prefName" : "北海道"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 2,
      "prefName" : "青森県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 3,
      "prefName" : "岩手県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 4,
      "prefName" : "宮城県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 5,
      "prefName" : "秋田県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 6,
      "prefName" : "山形県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 7,
      "prefName" : "福島県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 8,
      "prefName" : "茨城県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 9,
      "prefName" : "栃木県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 10,
      "prefName" : "群馬県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 11,
      "prefName" : "埼玉県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 12,
      "prefName" : "千葉県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 13,
      "prefName" : "東京都"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 14,
      "prefName" : "神奈川県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 15,
      "prefName" : "新潟県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 16,
      "prefName" : "富山県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 17,
      "prefName" : "石川県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 18,
      "prefName" : "福井県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 19,
      "prefName" : "山梨県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 20,
      "prefName" : "長野県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 21,
      "prefName" : "岐阜県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 22,
      "prefName" : "静岡県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 23,
      "prefName" : "愛知県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 24,
      "prefName" : "三重県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 25,
      "prefName" : "滋賀県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 26,
      "prefName" : "京都府"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 27,
      "prefName" : "大阪府"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 28,
      "prefName" : "兵庫県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 29,
      "prefName" : "奈良県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 30,
      "prefName" : "和歌山県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 31,
      "prefName" : "鳥取県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 32,
      "prefName" : "島根県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 33,
      "prefName" : "岡山県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 34,
      "prefName" : "広島県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 35,
      "prefName" : "山口県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 36,
      "prefName" : "徳島県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 37,
      "prefName" : "香川県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 38,
      "prefName" : "愛媛県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 39,
      "prefName" : "高知県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 40,
      "prefName" : "福岡県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 41,
      "prefName" : "佐賀県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 42,
      "prefName" : "長崎県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 43,
      "prefName" : "熊本県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 44,
      "prefName" : "大分県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 45,
      "prefName" : "宮崎県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 46,
      "prefName" : "鹿児島県"
    },
    {
      "prefCode" : 47,
      "prefName" : "沖縄県"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code, at least what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and push data of `prefCode` and `prefName` in corresponding array and destructure the result.

```js
let response = { "message" : null, "result" : [ { "prefCode" : 1, "prefName" : "北海道" }, { "prefCode" : 2, "prefName" : "青森県" }, { "prefCode" : 3, "prefName" : "岩手県" }, { "prefCode" : 4, "prefName" : "宮城県" }, { "prefCode" : 5, "prefName" : "秋田県" }, { "prefCode" : 6, "prefName" : "山形県" }, { "prefCode" : 7, "prefName" : "福島県" }, { "prefCode" : 8, "prefName" : "茨城県" }, { "prefCode" : 9, "prefName" : "栃木県" }, { "prefCode" : 10, "prefName" : "群馬県" }, { "prefCode" : 11, "prefName" : "埼玉県" }, { "prefCode" : 12, "prefName" : "千葉県" }, { "prefCode" : 13, "prefName" : "東京都" }, { "prefCode" : 14, "prefName" : "神奈川県" }, { "prefCode" : 15, "prefName" : "新潟県" }, { "prefCode" : 16, "prefName" : "富山県" }, { "prefCode" : 17, "prefName" : "石川県" }, { "prefCode" : 18, "prefName" : "福井県" }, { "prefCode" : 19, "prefName" : "山梨県" }, { "prefCode" : 20, "prefName" : "長野県" }, { "prefCode" : 21, "prefName" : "岐阜県" }, { "prefCode" : 22, "prefName" : "静岡県" }, { "prefCode" : 23, "prefName" : "愛知県" }, { "prefCode" : 24, "prefName" : "三重県" }, { "prefCode" : 25, "prefName" : "滋賀県" }, { "prefCode" : 26, "prefName" : "京都府" }, { "prefCode" : 27, "prefName" : "大阪府" }, { "prefCode" : 28, "prefName" : "兵庫県" }, { "prefCode" : 29, "prefName" : "奈良県" }, { "prefCode" : 30, "prefName" : "和歌山県" }, { "prefCode" : 31, "prefName" : "鳥取県" }, { "prefCode" : 32, "prefName" : "島根県" }, { "prefCode" : 33, "prefName" : "岡山県" }, { "prefCode" : 34, "prefName" : "広島県" }, { "prefCode" : 35, "prefName" : "山口県" }, { "prefCode" : 36, "prefName" : "徳島県" }, { "prefCode" : 37, "prefName" : "香川県" }, { "prefCode" : 38, "prefName" : "愛媛県" }, { "prefCode" : 39, "prefName" : "高知県" }, { "prefCode" : 40, "prefName" : "福岡県" }, { "prefCode" : 41, "prefName" : "佐賀県" }, { "prefCode" : 42, "prefName" : "長崎県" }, { "prefCode" : 43, "prefName" : "熊本県" }, { "prefCode" : 44, "prefName" : "大分県" }, { "prefCode" : 45, "prefName" : "宮崎県" }, { "prefCode" : 46, "prefName" : "鹿児島県" }, { "prefCode" : 47, "prefName" : "沖縄県" } ] },
  {PrefectureCode, PrefectureName} = response.result.reduce((r,{prefCode, prefName}) => {
    r.PrefectureCode.push(prefCode);
    r.PrefectureName.push(prefName);
    return r;
  },{PrefectureCode: [], PrefectureName: []});
console.log(PrefectureCode, PrefectureName);
```